# Error while converting number to char and adding an extra char oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two columns where VAL_ID is a varchar and id is number. I am trying to convert id to varchar and compare it to VAL_ID (id can be 123 and val can be either 123 or D123) so I have to do both conditions, but I am getting an error:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

My select:

```
select  TO_NUMBER(VAL_ID) per_val, id p_val
from doc d inner join emp p
on p.VAL_ID = TO_CHAR(d.id) 
or p.VAL_ID = CONCAT('D',TO_CHAR(d.id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `select`.  Why are you converting something that starts with a `D` to a number?  You can just do:

```
select p.VAL_ID as per_val, d.id as p_val
from doc d inner join
     emp p
     on p.VAL_ID = TO_CHAR(d.id) or
        p.VAL_ID = CONCAT('D', TO_CHAR(d.id));
```

If you need the number component, then just use `d.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem.